# How to interpret this PCA plot?

Tags: pca, data-visualization

[image: PCA Plot 1][image: PCA Plot 2]

Legend: Each point represents a trial. The circles and pluses represent two different conditions of the experiment. Each color represents a different subject. We used five variables. There are 20 experiments, two of them are pictured above. The axes are the first two principal components (the first two principal components explain an average of ~70% of the variance in all of the experiments)

I'm having difficulty drawing meaningful interpretations from these plots. It seems that individual subjects are very consistent when they work under the same condition. Beyond that, I don't know what else to make of it. I cannot post the raw data - my apologies. Does anybody have any suggestions about how to interpret these data?

Edit: All of the variables are scaled to mean = 0, sd = 1

Comment: You want to determine what the principle component summarizes (is it an average or difference of certain variables) and then compare that summary to the empirical data. This is where you can determine if your assessment is correct (if there is a linear relationship between the principle component and the data). Looking at the scaling, did you make sure that all the data is on the same scale? PCA is sensitive to the order of magnitude of individual features.

Comment: I normalized the data by variable. One thing that I just noticed is that variables 2 and 4 almost always have the same values. The covariance between the two is .938. How could we interpret that?

Comment: Are you plotting the coefficients against each other?

Comment: I'm examining svd(A)$v and cov(A)

Comment: Can you say more about the data? What are the original variables? What are the trials? Are they yes/no, success/failure, etc?

Answer (score 4):

In general, this is hard to answer without knowing more about the experiment. But given what you have presented, here are some patterns that seem evident:

1. There is high variance in individuals' response to the two different
   conditions in the lower figure. Pluses and circles are very close
   (if not on top of each
       other) for most individuals, indicating that the condition did not influence their
       response. But in some (pink, purple & red), circles have much higher
       PC1 values.
2. In the upper figure, individuals appear to exhibit a more consistent
   difference between treatments. In most cases, pluses have a higher
   PC1 value, although there are exceptions (e.g. purple).
3. Also in the upper figure: there is a negative relationship between
   PC1 & PC2 values in different trials for each individual within each
   condition. It would require a lot more information about the
   experiment to explain what this might mean.